# Cloud masking with the Descartes Labs Platform Scenes API

Tags: masking, cloud-cover, descartes-labs-platform

I have created a scene collection in the Descartes Labs Platform using the Scenes search function (dl.scenes.search) for my area of interest and sensor of choice (Sentinel-2). I would like to iterate through the scenes in the collection and mask for clouds using the cloud-mask band before creating a composite with only clear pixels. How would you approach this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a cloud mask directly to a stack of pixel values before compositing the scenes together. There is a basic derived band computed on all products with  red, green, and blue bands called `derived:visual_cloud_mask` but for Sentinel-2:L1C there is also a separate "DLCloud" product that provides a variety of cloud mask types that are of better quality. To apply those, fetch a SceneCollection across the same AOI and datetime range you queried Sentinel-2:L1C and apply the mask with numpy.

First, your imports and the AOI. This is a rather cloudy region over the [Sierra Nevada de Santa Marta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Nevada_de_Santa_Marta) in Colombia.

```py
import descarteslabs as dl
import numpy as np

aoi = dl.scenes.DLTile.from_latlon(10.783, -73.669 ,60,256, 0)
start_datetime = '2017-06-01'
end_datetime = '2017-09-01'
```

Then, fetch your Sentinel RGB data using the [SceneCollection.stack](https://docs.descarteslabs.com/descarteslabs/scenes/docs/scenecollection.html#descarteslabs.scenes.scenecollection.SceneCollection.stack) method.

```py
sentinel_scenes, sentinel_ctx = dl.scenes.search(
    aoi.geometry,
    products=["sentinel-2:L1C"],
    start_datetime=start_datetime, end_datetime=end_datetime,
    limit=None
)
sentinel_rgb_stack = sentinel_scenes.stack('red green blue', 
                                           sentinel_ctx, 
                                           processing_level='surface')
```

Do the same for the DLCloud masks. We'll use the `valid_cloudfree` band in this example. Use the same geocontext returned from the Sentinel scene search to ensure we are working with arrays in the same spatial reference system and resolution.

```py
dlcloud_scenes, dlcloud_ctx = dl.scenes.search(
    aoi.geometry,
    products=["sentinel-2:L1C:dlcloud:v1"],
    start_datetime=start_datetime, end_datetime=end_datetime,
    limit=None
)

dlcloud_valid_cloudfree_stack = dlcloud_scenes.stack('valid_cloudfree', 
                                                     sentinel_ctx , 
                                                     data_type='Byte')
```

Apply the cloud masks to the RGB data. You'll need to repeat the mask for the 3 bands downloaded to use the Numpy masked array [masked_where](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html) method

```py
dlcloud_valid_cloudfree_stack = np.repeat(a=dlcloud_valid_cloudfree_stack,
                                          repeats=3,
                                          axis=1)
```

Mask out the pixel values where `valid_cloud_free` is equal to 0.

```py
cloudfree_rgb_stack = np.ma.masked_where(dlcloud_valid_cloudfree_stack==0,
                                         sentinel_rgb_stack)
```

Display the results to sanity check what you have done. First the unmasked, cloudy pixels using a simple median mosaic through time,

```py
sentinel_rgb_mosaic = np.ma.median(sentinel_rgb_stack, axis=0)
dl.scenes.display(sentinel_rgb_mosaic)
```

[image: Yuck]

And finally with the mask applied.

```py
cloudfree_mosaic = np.ma.median(cloudfree_rgb_stack, axis=0)
dl.scenes.display(cloudfree_mosaic)
```

[image: Better!]

Here is a [complete notebook](https://gist.github.com/jeremy-dl/43c2d9abe11e516be65e8866007ece60) to get you started.